# RMagick not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

I'd appreciate any help with this - I'm sure it's a simple mistake.

The location of my app is `C:\sanj\rubyjobs`. I have installed ImageMagick successfully in its default location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick`.

I have also installed rmagick the gem by running `gem install rmagick --local` in `C:\sanj\rubyjobs\vendor\RMagick Extract`.

Upon running `bundle install`, I get the following error:

```
C:/Sanj/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb  
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes  
Invalid drive specification.  
Unable to get ImageMagick version  
*** extconf.rb failed ***  
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of  
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more  
details.  You may need configuration options.  

Provided configuration options:  
        --with-opt-dir  
        --without-opt-dir  
        --with-opt-include  
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include  
        --with-opt-lib  
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib  
        --with-make-prog  
        --without-make-prog  
        --srcdir=.  
        --curdir  
        --ruby=C:/Sanj/Ruby192/bin/ruby

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.  
Results logged to C:/Sanj/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RM
agick/gem_make.out
```

Setup: Windows Vista 64-bit, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3, Heroku

**EDIT**
When I run `identify -version` from ruby command prompt, I get:
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.6-8 2009-10-03 Q8 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC

If ImageMagick is installed and the prompt is finding it, why is it saying it can't get the version??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is there

http://phosphor-escence.blogspot.com/2010/12/if-you-fail-install-rmagick-on-mingw.html

But, unfortunatelly, RMagick is not continued to maintain...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [RMagick FAQ](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-faq.html#win).  According to them, you shouldn't be installing the official RMagick gem, but rather using the gem that is bundled with the ImageMagick installer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to get RMagic working! https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki

It's not a simple mistake. It's poorly designed. Things like needing ImageMagick at the front of your path are just arcane! It doesn't work with the latest version of ImageMagick 6.8 though.

Comment: THanks Chloe but I'm running OS X.

Comment: What?! You're path said `C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick` and `C:/Sanj/Ruby192/bin/ruby.exe`

Comment: haha - forget that last comment. When I posted this question back in 2010 I was running Windows. Nevermind!

Comment: Do you like Mac better? Thinking of getting a new computer.

Comment: I've found it better for coding - among other things, it seems more stable, the support software is usually better, and installations are easier.

Answer (score 0):

The just released 2.13.2 version of RMagick should work with ImageMagick 6.8, and also has fixes for ruby 1.9.3. See https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick.